# Advanced-rest-client: How can I increase the request timeout while using the advanced-rest-client?

Tags: connection-timeout, advanced-rest-client

I am calling a rest controller on my localhost, passing in bunch of request headers. The call is made fine but due to processing timeout the advanced-rest-client timesout and doesn't show the result from the server. how can i increase the timeout so it can wait for server to complete the request and display the result? I would appreciate your hints on this.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Is the server timing out or is it advances-rest-client? What type of server are you hitting? Do you have control of the server?

Comment: not the server, the advance-rest-client timesout. i'm looking for setting on the REST tool where to configure the timeout.

Comment: You could try using Postman and see if that is more friendly on timeouts. How long before it times out? Also, you could try the CLI tool curl and make the request using that. Typically requests that take a long time happen in the background and you don't await a response. Also, you might be interested in learning about event driven architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust request timeout in application settings. In version 14 it is possible to adjust request timeout directly in the request editor.

Comment: I have a default timeout left in the settings (45secs) and still the request times out immediately (it's a POST request); I do see the server processing the request normally. What can be the reason? BTW, when I turn on the request's own settings (it is set to 90secs timeout) - the timeout config IS taken correctly and no timeout seen. So it looks like the default timeout settings are not applied or something...